# GetSaveAsFilename default folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am using `GetSaveAsFilename` in VBA for Excel. Is there any way to give this a default folder to open up to? For example, I always want it to start at `C:\MyDocuments\Music` when it is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `FileDialog` object offers way more flexibility than `GetSaveAsFilename` (and its sibling `GetOpenFilename`). Example:

```
Dim tuneSaver As FileDialog
Set tuneSaver = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With tuneSaver
    .Title = "Save this tune as..."
    .InitialFileName = "C:\MyDocuments\Music\"
    ' Set other properties here...
    .Show
End With
```

Note that an `.InitialFileName` longer than 256 characters will cause a run-time error.

See [VBA help on `FileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa219843%28office.11%29.aspx). It has quite a few useful properties, including e.g. `AllowMultiSelect` (though admittedly this one is irrelevant when saving).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Is there a way you can set the "Save as type" to a something but the default as well?  It is defaulting to the latest/greatest version of excel but I want to set it to the older ".xls" format (2003 and prior).

Comment: Hmm, maybe [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210589%28v=office.11%29.aspx) will help. However, I'm afraid the `FileDialog` object isn't available in Excel versions later than 2003 (that's what I hear, anyway) so your question may be moot.

Comment: Thanks - I had read that page ... however, I couldn't figure it out.  The report is generated in 2007 but I need to save the output as a 2003 document.  It's working pretty good now.  Was just trying to remove one more stumbling block. Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is old, but I thought I'd add that FileSearch was deprecated in Excel 2007, not FileDialog -- it is alive and well (if http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208503(v=office.12).aspx is to be believed)

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
x = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="C:\mydocuments\music\", _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.*), *.*")
```

However, if you have spaces in the filespec it gets a little trickier. For example, this:

```
x = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Music", _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.*), *.*")
```

only gets as far as My Documents and thinks that My Music is the filename. Hope this helps.

Comment: missed the \ of the end.  this makes it a path, not a file

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ChDir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243256(v=vs.60).aspx) before `GetSaveAsFilename`.

Answer (score 0):

ChDir can be used (using the answer of @Mark Ransom) shown in this example code:

```
Dim workBook As workBook
Set workBook = ActiveWorkbook

ChDir (workBook.Path) ' Set Default folder

saveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=workBook.Name, _
                                         fileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Worksheet (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

' Check whether the name specified is usable
If saveName <> False Then
    workBook.SaveAs Filename:=saveName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
```

Hope this clarifies ChDir a bit.