# getting save as file name in word

Tags: vba, ms-word, save

In the code below the file name is hard coded, but I want the user to be able to pick it.

I was reading about `GetSaveAsFilename` but I get an error when using it: "method or member not found".

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.txt), *.txt")
```

This is written for Word 2010. Am I wrong in thinking `GetSaveAsFilename` is available in word VBA?

```
 Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="Questionnaire01-05-20122.txt", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=True, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False, _
         AllowSubstitutions:=False, LineEnding:=wdCRLF, CompatibilityMode:=0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a default path including filename like so to the dialog, ie

```
Sub SaveName()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim StrPath As String
    'provide default filename
    StrPath = "c:\temp\test.docx"
    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = StrPath
        If .Display <> 0 Then
            strFileName = .Name
        Else
            strFileName = "User Cancelled"
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox strFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: one thing that returns only the name not the full path? but sure I can work that out :) cheers for the examples people

Answer (score 5):

I didn't realize that Word doesn't have GetSaveAsFileName or GetOpenFileName methods (which Excel has).  But it doesn't.  Instead you can try the SaveAs FileDialog ([2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213120%28v=office.11%29.aspx), [2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208503%28v=office.12%29.aspx), [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff196794.aspx)):

```
Sub ShowSaveAsDialog()
Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
dlgSaveAs.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: +1  See [this worked out example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148173/getsaveasfilename-default-folder/5165166#5165166) of how to use `FileDialog`.

Comment: Doug, I added a slightly different answer as I didn't think the code above made it clear how to retrieve the user entry (I think it needs something like `dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)`)

Comment: yep I had this but as Brettdj says this does not celarly return the file name

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strFilePath, strFileName
strFilePath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\"
strFileName = "put-filename-here.docx"

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    .Name = strFilePath & strFileName
    .Show
End With
```