# How to name file based on data in bookmarks

Tags: vba, ms-word, filenames

I'm trying to save a Microsoft Word 2010 document with a name based off of a template.

I have a template form that has bookmark names:
ProcNo (Bookmark for Procedure Number)
RevNo (Bookmark for Revision Number)

I would like to open the Save As window with the file name inserted in the following format: “ProcNo” Rev “RevNo” – Attachment 4 Traveler

Where “ProcNo” is text drawn from Bookmark for Procedure Number and “RevNo” is text drawn from Bookmark for Revision Number

I would then select file destination in the Save As window.

I tried using the macro recorder and clicking File, Save As, and then Browse to open the Save As window and typed document name as “ABC” to get a feel for what the code would look like; but had following issues:

I don’t know the code for opening the Save As window.

I don't know the code for inserting the file name in Save As window containing the aforementioned file naming format.

The macro recorder gave me following:

```vb
Sub SaveAs()
'
' SaveAs Macro
'
'
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\bzimme1\Documents\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="ABC.docx", FileFormat:= _
        wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
        :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
        :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404689/getting-save-as-file-name-in-word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting save as file name in word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404689/getting-save-as-file-name-in-word)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim sFlNm As String
With ActiveDocument
  sFlNm = .Bookmarks("ProcNo").Range.Text & " Rev " & .Bookmarks("RevNo").Range.Text & " – Attachment 4 Traveler"
End With
With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
  .Name = sFlNm
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That's it! It works great. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. It is set to:

1. Get information from the "Title" built-in document property
2. Get and append information from the first Content Control in the document for use in the filename
3. Append the date at the end
4. Preserve the current default save folder for restoration
5. Set to save in a particular folder without changing the default save path for other documents
6. Display the SaveAs dialog with the information in the dialog

You could use similar statements to get information from your bookmarks. See [Working With Bookmarks](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/WorkWithBookmarks.htm) by Ibby on the Word MVP site.

```
Sub FileSaveAs()
    ' Run as substitute for FileSave to add date to default document names
    ' Charles Kenyon 2017, 2019, 2020
    ' Appends content control info and date to Title Document property when saving the first time
    On Error Resume Next
   
    If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) > 0 Then
      ' The document has already been saved at least once.
      ' Just save and exit the macro.
      ActiveDocument.Save
      Exit Sub
    End If
    '
    '
    Dim strName As String, dlgSave As Dialog
    Dim strPath As String   'Holder for current path
    Const strTEMPPATH As String = "full path where" ' where document will be stored
    Let strPath = Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath)
    Set dlgSave = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
    strName = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value 'get name in title
'    InputBox (strName)
    strName = strName & " " & ActiveDocument.ContentControls(1).Range.Text 'add name from first content control
'    InputBox (strName)
    strName = strName & " " & Format((Year(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "20##") & "-" & _
        Format((Month(Now() + 1) Mod 100), "0#") & "-" & _
        Format((Day(Now()) Mod 100), "0#") 'add date
    With dlgSave
        .Name = strTEMPPATH & strName
        .Show
    End With
    '   Reset save path
    Let Application.Options.DefaultFilePath(wdDocumentsPath) = strPath
    '   empty object
    Set dlgSave = Nothing
    OnError GoTo -1
End Sub
```