# GetSaveAsFilename with spaces in directory name

Tags: excel, vba, directory, spaces, savefiledialog

I have a code which enables templates to be saved in a fixed directory with custom but suggested filenames. However, I also want to apply this to a different template in a directory whith a space in its name.

I read in a different question an answer about spaces making it more complex. ([GetSaveAsFilename default folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148173/getsaveasfilename-default-folder)) an answer:

```
this works:

x = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="C:\mydocuments\music\", _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.*), *.*")
```

However, if you have spaces in the filespec it gets a little trickier. For example, this:

```
x = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Music", _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.*), *.*")
```

Only gets as far as `My Documents` and thinks that `My Music` is the filename. Hope this helps.)

So, what to do to have the right directory with a space in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your path in quotes:

```
"""%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Music"""
```

to get spaces recognized as part of the path instead of separator.

Comment: thanks, After adding the correct number of quotes, de default save directory is correct. I have one more wish concerning my save script, can I add that to my question? It is about adding the workbookname to the initial filename.. (which is not working with the script I made)

Comment: probably it's better to mark this as solved and open up a new question for that, asking your specific and new question.