# Excel VBA - Save As suggested filename and filepath from a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in an Excel Workbook, that is connected to a button that says *Export*

When I click the button, it triggers the *Export XML* dialog and I have to manually search for a folder to export it into and enter the filename.

Since the folders in my Documents are named exactly the same as the value of the Cell A24, i would like it to direct itself into the correct folder and suggest me a filename based on the value of the Cell A24 with some extra text behind it.

So far i have this in the VBA:

```
Public Sub ExportToXML()

    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim POFilePath As String
    Dim FOFilePath As String
    Dim POFileName As String
    Dim FOFileName As String
    Dim XMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xAttribute As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim xElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim xElementRoot As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    MainSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    POFilePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Range("A24")
    
    FOFilePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Range("D22") & " " & Range("A22")
    
    POFileName = "_report " & Range("D13").value & " " & Range("F13").value & ".xml"
    
    FOFileName = "_report " & Range("D13").value & " " & Range("F13").value & ".xml"
    
    If Range("A24").value = "0" Then
        
        strFilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FOFilePath & FOFileName, fileFilter:="XML files (*.xml),*.xml", Title:="Save FileAs...")
        
    Else
    
        strFilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(POFilePath & POFileName, fileFilter:="XML files (*.xml),*.xml", Title:="Save FileAs...")
        
    End If

    If strFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
```

This gives me the right filename suggestion, but it doesn't direct me to the folder and goes to Desktop.

Any help would be appriciated!

EDIT:

I tried merging the Strings together a bit more and came up with this:

```
Public Sub ExportToXML()

    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim POFilePath As String
    Dim FOFilePath As String
    Dim XMLDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Dim xAttribute As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim xElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim xElementRoot As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    MainSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    POFilePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Range("A24") & Range("A24").value & "_report " & Range("D13").value & " " & Range("F13").value & ".xml"
    
    FOFilePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Range("D22") & " " & Range("A22") & "_report " & Range("D13").value & " " & Range("F13").value & ".xml"
    
    
    If Range("A24").value = "0" Then
        
        strFilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FOFilePath, fileFilter:="XML files (*.xml),*.xml", Title:="Save FileAs...")
        
    Else
    
        strFilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(POFilePath, fileFilter:="XML files (*.xml),*.xml", Title:="Save FileAs...")
        
    End If

    If strFilePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
```

The problem is, that VBA thinks that in:

```
POFilePath = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Range("A24") & Range("A24").value & "_report " & Range("D13").value & " " & Range("F13").value & ".xml"
```

the first Range("A24") belongs to the filename part and doesn't continue on with the filepath. So if the value in A24 was "test", then this suggests saving the xml to Desktop with the filename testttest_report 11 2020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetSaveAsFilename default folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148173/getsaveasfilename-default-folder)

Comment: I would still like to be able to use GetSaveAsFilename

Comment: It's getting a little bit confusing what is part of the folder name and what of the file name. I assume you miss a `\` between folder and file name. Check the content of `POFilePath ` resp. `FOFilePath` in the debugger.

Comment: Sorry, SO messed up my comment, wanted to write that there is a backslash missing.

Comment: I see! I added backslash and it works wonders. You are a genius. Thanks so much for the help, i appreciate it!